# How to implement REST web-services?

Tags: web-services, rest

I am trying to learn Java Web-Service using REST architecture.
So far I have created a class but I don't know how to consume that service.
Here's my code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;


@Path("/SericeCreation")
public class SericeCreation {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String display(){
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

Now, I want to call this display method.
Can anyone help me to understand how this can be achieved?

Comment: Also, If I changes the format to (application/json) what all changes are required in my calling and called class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a very simplified point of view, rest services are bound to Http calls, in your example the `@GET` annotation tells you that this method is accessed by making an `HTTP GET` call.

You can simply point your browser to the url generated for this service and you should see the "hello" response. The url is something like this `http://<server>:<port>/<AppContext>/<rest-servlet-mapping>/SericeCreation` where:

- `<server>` is your server name. Typically `localhost`
- `<port>` the default server port number. If you are usin Jboss 8080
- `<AppContext>` typically the name of your applicaction (War file)
- `<rest-servlet-mapping>` the RestEasy or Jersey frameworks servlet path
- `/SericeCreation` this comes from the `@Path` annotation that is used
  in your class.

Another way to intereact with your services is using a Rest Client like this [one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo).

And of course, if you want to create a java client you can use the `apache http client library`, `java.net.*` package or others. Remember, rest services are accessed by making http calls.

I recommend you read this two tutorials to get a general idea of rest architecture.

- [Rest RefCard](https://dzone.com/refcardz/rest-foundations-restful)
- [Beginner's Guide](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340)

This great [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/) shows you a lot of examples using Jersey or RestEasy in order to implement Java Rest Services.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. It did helped me. Will try more